# Problem to run Firebase admin sdk on intellij java project

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, apple-m1

I am trying to run firebase admin sdk (I'm using a java application backend) on a mac m1.
I'm using:

- intellij IDE
- gradle 7.1
- javafx lib
- jdk 11

The problem is that when I try to look for a cloud firestore or real time reference, the error LOG stack is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @2c95cec4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)

[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 2147483648 bytes (maybe)
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/g0/69ygs0z53t3dq_lw7slqkj400000gn/T (java.io.tmpdir)
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /var/folders/g0/69ygs0z53t3dq_lw7slqkj400000gn/T (io.netty.tmpdir)
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.deleteLibAfterLoading: true
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.tryPatchShadedId: true
[JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_aarch_64', trying other loading mechanism.
```

I cannot write the all stack because it is classified as spam, but in particular i have this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_aarch_64.jnilib
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_aarch_64.jnilib
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative.jnilib
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_aarch_64.jnilib
```

I have not this problem in windows 10.
I tried to import in gradle netty `implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.72.Final'` but nothing has changed.

Can someone help me?